# AVAudioPlayer can't play sound until using debug script

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 with iOS 9 and having issue with playing sound by AVAudioPlayer. I've tried all possible solution out there and nothing works Here is my code

```
        let mp3Url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BCA", withExtension:"mp3")!

        var player = AVAudioPlayer()

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3Url)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
```

The sound won't play until I put a breakpoint at **player.play()** and using **po player**. Then the sound will be played.

Any idea will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    func playSound(){
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "alert_song", withExtension: "mp3") else {
            print("MP3 resource not found.")
            return
        }

        print("Music to play : \(String(describing: url))")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

Comment: This works for me! If I use player as global variable then it will be OK

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    var player = AVAudioPlayer() //global variables will otherwise be deadlock

    let mp3Url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BCA", withExtension:"mp3")!

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3Url)
        player.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
```